# My 240 GB SSD shown as having 2MB

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am using Lenovo IdeaPad Z500
My SSD harddrive is SP ( silicon power ) S60 (240GB).

On the SSD was installed 2 operating systems: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Last night I couldn't boot my PC and got a message:

> Operating system not found

I assembled my SSD drive and connect it to another PC with simple SATA cable.

When I checked the size of my drive I saw it appears to have only 2 MB

[image: screenshot from command output, Disk 2 2046 KB]

Is there a way to solve it or is my SSD failing?

Comment: I think that the partition table is affected. Try checking the partition table of your SSD in `GParted`(If Ubuntu) or `Create or format hard disk partitions`(if WIndows).